# getting data from server and displaying in spinner in android

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

i want to get countries names from a particular URL and then want to display them in a spinner
using [JSON].
can anybody please help me..provide me some simple examples if you can thanks...

Comment: Did you tried anything before asking question here?

Comment: @arsh.somal Please post some code and what you have tried?

Comment: @arsh.somal Google is the best bet if you are just looking for example.

Comment: You can refer this tutorial. http://simpleandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/06/fetching-data-from-server-and-setting.html

Comment: [{"id":"1","cityname":"aaa","statename":"Te"},{"id":"2","cityname":"Fo","statename":"T"},{"id":"3","cityname":"Ig","statename":"Ts"},{"id":"4","cityname":"Oe","statename":"Ts"}] i have this array please tell how to get these values into jasonArray. thanks

Comment: Before asking the question please google first. you can find the solution of the problem from this link. try this http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/